# Create an if statement in Bash commandline (not a script)

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am trying to create an if statement in bash command line, not a script but a statement can be typed into the command line with no returns because I have to run this script through a groovy command line call.

```
if [cat $(find ./ -name userId.txt) == "517980"]; then cat $(find ./ -name userId.txt); fi
```

The Jenkins groovy script looks like this

```
node("puppet-$ENVIRONMENT") {
  sh "/opt/puppet/bin/puppet module uninstall ${module} || echo 'NOT INSTALLED!'"
  sh "pwd"
  sh "rm -rf *"
  //unarchive the tar in the remote file system and install it
  unarchive mapping: ['*.*': './']
  sh 'if [cat $(find ./ -name userId.txt) == "517980"]; then echo "it works"; fi'
  sh "ls -alrt"
  sh '/opt/puppet/bin/puppet module install --force $(find ./ -name *.tar.gz)'
}
```

Comment: error?  exception?  what seems to be the problem? and `sh` is something alike `['sh','-c',cmd].execute()`, right?

Comment: Its the bash that is the problem not the groovy I need a one line command that will compare two strings in bash

Comment: shouldn' that be `... [ cat...` (spaces around the `[` and shouldn't the shell complaing on that already?

Comment: `sh "rm -rf *"` -- yikes! better be **absolutely sure**  your current directory is what you think it is!

Comment: glenn jackman:  I appreciate you concern, this is a proof of concept.  I will clean it up properly once I can get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file=$(find ./ -name userId.txt) && [ -n "$file" ] && { contents=$(cat "$file"); [ "$contents" == "517980" ] && echo "$contents"; }
```

- don't need to run `find` or `cat` more than once
- `[` is actually a *command* not mere syntax: it needs a space to separate it from its arguments
- You're missing `$()` around your `cat` calls

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I think I understand, a little better, how to construct one line scripts in bash

Comment: I'm not sure what OP is trying to achieve, but wouldn't it be (nearly) equivalent to this? `find ./ -name userId.txt -type f -exec sh -c 'read -r line < "$1"; [ "$line" = 517980 ] && echo "$line"' _ {} \; -quit`